# I am new to web scraping on Python. How to filter only link and article title?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like from The hackernews website to filter my news , for specific String.
I would like it to email me the links that interest me.
The problem is that I need the link and the title of the article in the email. Unfortunately I get all the content with div , span etc.
Thank you in advance for your help and best regards.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import redis
from password import bot_email_pw
import requests

# source
class Scraper:
def __init__(self, keywords):
    self.markup = requests.get('https://thehackernews.com/').text
    self.keywords = keywords

# parser
def parse(self):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.markup, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.findAll('a') #hackernews
    """links = soup.findAll("div", class_="home-desc")"""
    self.saved_links = []
    for link in links:
        for keyword in self.keywords:
            if keyword in link.text:
                self.saved_links.append(link)
    print(self.saved_links)

# storage
def store(self):
    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    for link in self.saved_links:
        r.set(link.text, str(link))

def email(self):
    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    links = [str(r.get(k)) for k in r.keys()]
    print(links)

    # email
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    fromEmail = "@gmail.com"
    toEmail = "@gmail.com"

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Link"
    msg['From'] = fromEmail
    msg['To'] = toEmail

    html = """
        <h4> %s links you might find interesting today: </h4>
        %s <br/></br>
    """ % (len(links), '<br/><br/>'.join(links))

    mime = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    msg.attach(mime)

    try:
        mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.starttls()
        mail.login(fromEmail, bot_email_pw)
        mail.sendmail(fromEmail, toEmail, msg.as_string())
        mail.quit()
        print(('Email sent!'))
    except Exception as exc:
        print('something might went wrong...%s' % exc)

    # free redis
    r.flushdb()


  s = Scraper(['malware'])
  s.parse()
  s.store()
  """s.email()"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your links more specific and simply append a tuple to your list:

```
self.saved_links.append((link.get('href'), link.text))
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://thehackernews.com/'
soup =BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

for a in soup.select('a.story-link'):
    print(a.get('href'), a.h2.text)
```

Comment: Thanks HedgeHog for help. But still I have problems.
I set function self.saved_links.append ((link.get('href'), link.text)).
  if keyword in link.text:
                self.saved_links.append((link.get('href'), link.text))
    print(self.saved_links)
Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/PycharmProjects/Skrypt4/main.py", line 78, in <module>
    s.store()
  File "/Users/david/PycharmProjects/Skrypt4/main.py", line 32, in store
    r.set(link.text, str(link))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: OK, I get the point. Primarily the answer was aimed at extracting the values, the use in storage would then simply have to be via `r.set(link)` or `r.set(link[0],link[1])` respectively. 
 Else skip appending tuple and use `r.set(link.text,link.get('href')`. Here it would be cool for future questions to focus the question as well as the [mcve] a bit more. happy coding.